# Using lapply with other values

Tags: r, tidyverse, lapply

I have a list of data frames named `x`, and I would like to subtract each data frame in the list by 1. If

```
values(x) <- 1 - values(x)
```

If I wanted to use the function `lapply` for this would it look like this?

```
values(x) <- 1 - lapply(x, function(l) values(x))
```

Thank you

Comment: Where is `values` defined? (Similarly, where do you use the `l` in `function(l)`?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess what you need might be

```
1-sapply(x,value)
```

or

```
sapply(x,function(v) 1-value(v))
```